# Bash: PS1 vs Prompt Command to set prompt and title

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, shell

Is there much difference between the following options regarding performance / efficiency for setting the prompt and the terminal title?
(apart from the extra call to `echo`)

1. Set PS1 to be the output of a command:

```
PS1="\$(my_fun)"
my_fun() {
  echo "my prompt"
}
```

2. Use `PROMPT_COMMAND` to set PS1 directly:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=_prompt_command
_prompt_command() {
    PS1="my prompt"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efficiency:

- `PS1="$(fun)"` will call the function *just once* (when the assignment is parsed) and will use a subshell process. It's the most efficient option if the output is completely static.
- `PROMPT_COMMAND=fun` will call the function *every time* (whenever the prompt is displayed) and will run it within the main shell process.
- `PS1="\$(fun)"` will call the function *every time* (whenever the prompt is displayed) and will spawn a subshell process every time, making it less efficient than PROMPT_COMMAND (but sometimes necessary; see the next section.)

Correctness:

- The contents of `PS1` are provided to Readline, which allows it to know the prompt width and correctly wrap your input if it no longer fits in a single line. When calling a function from PS1 (e.g. `PS1="\$(foo)"`) you need to wrap invisible sequences with `\001` and `\002` instead of the usual `\[` and `\]`.
- The results of `PROMPT_COMMAND` are directly shown on screen and not known to Readline. If you try to use this method exclusively (that is, together with an empty `PS1=""`) you'll notice that as soon as the input is longer than a single line, the cursor will no longer make sense and you can no longer backspace from line 2 to line 1.
- For multi-line shell prompts, it doesn't matter how the previous lines are shown, as long as the *last* line is still shown through `PS1`.
- It also doesn't matter what you use to set the terminal title, since it isn't counted into the prompt width anyway.